# Nearby cities or town from my current location

Tags: java, android, google-maps

How to find Nearby cities or town from my current location in android. i can get the nearest places like ATM, hospital. But, i couldn't get the nearest town or city names.

Comment: You can try Places API or the Maps API from Google...  What have you already tried?

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=lat,lng&radius=5000&types=food&sensor=true&key=APIKEY

I tried this url.. i can't get city from this url

Comment: As the output in the URL says, your API-key is invalid. Generate a new key in console.developers.google.com and try with that.

Comment: I didn't mention the api key in that url..

Comment: Google places does much finer grained places.  There is no city information.  If you wanted your current city you could do it by looking at the address of the nearest place, but it won't find towns around you.

Comment: @karthik Have u done this? I need also same this. Can you help to find nearby city

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

https://github.com/yangjiandong/proAndroid4DevCode/blob/master/Full%20Worked%20Sample%20Projects/Chapter_13_Where_Am_I_Part_3/src/com/paad/whereami/WhereAmI.java#L14

```
     private void updateWithNewLocation(Location location) {
    TextView myLocationText;
    myLocationText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myLocationText);

    String latLongString = "No location found";
    String addressString = "No address found";

    if (location != null) {
      double lat = location.getLatitude();
      double lng = location.getLongitude();
      latLongString = "Lat:" + lat + "\nLong:" + lng;

      double latitude = location.getLatitude();
      double longitude = location.getLongitude();
      Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

      try {
        List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
          Address address = addresses.get(0);

          for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)
            sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");

          sb.append(address.getLocality()).append("\n");
          sb.append(address.getPostalCode()).append("\n");
          sb.append(address.getCountryName());
        }
        addressString = sb.toString();
      } catch (IOException e) {}
    }

    myLocationText.setText("Your Current Position is:\n" +
                            latLongString + "\n\n" + addressString);
  }

  private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      updateWithNewLocation(location);
    }
```

Comment: I can get current location address only from the above code.. i need near cities or towns name around 10 or 15 kilometers.

Answer (score 0):

This link might help you:

[from openhub]

http://code.openhub.net/file?fid=R-hjGyDqc9mbq2WulRngRVtnZZw&cid=8c3CtAuq0fw&s=Nearby%20cities%20or%20town%20from%20my%20current%20location&pp=0&fl=Java&ff=1&filterChecked=true&fp=489947&mp,=1&ml=0&me=1&md=1&projSelected=true#L0

Answer (score 0):

I am providing a link where you can find working source code which i have tried in my application Here I am posting link hope you found this useful.

[Web link](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-nearby-places-using-google-places-api-and-google-map-android-api-v2/)

[image: here is output of code]

Comment: using this link i can get near by places only.. i want nearby cities

Comment: please take look at this  site http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/